# problems exporting Solar php5 root directory from localhost to live server or even other computer

Tags: php, directory, export, symlink, web-frameworks

Ok,
This seems like something that would be obvious, but I haven't been able to figure this out.

I just started using Solar PHP5 Framework http://solarphp.com. It is a great php5 framework. But with any new framework the is a learning curve.

**Issue:**  Solar uses many pre-written scripts to make directories and files for you. Making it easy to rapidly deploy a site. Being that it uses these scripts, it makes symbolic links to files and directories. (Example: Chapter 1 in the manual) This is great until you need to export your entire root directory to upload to your server or make another instance on another development computer. The problem for me is, when I do this, the files are editable, but do not reflect any changes when I refresh a page. Its like it doesn't update any code. The only way I can accomplish changes or updates, is to (essentially) run the site set-up each time, which involves running all the setup scripts, setting up the DB connections, etc. This is a total pain.

**Question** Is there any advice out there on doing this where I can just export the working root directory, to easily upload to server or other dev machine, without having to run those scripts over and over again. I know its something easy but I do not know exactly what to search for.

Is the a certain method for exporting directories/files that use symbolic links?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using rsync instead of ftp to deploy the site. rsync will respect symlinks. Of course you will need have ssh access or mount the server over ftp/sftp with FUSE. If youre using SVN you could also ssh into the server and do an svn export or checkout.

Comment: Well I plan on having an SVN set up by the time its done, but my main problem is exporting from one dev machine to another. Example: I need a replica of the entire site from PC 1 to PC 2. When I export (in eclipse), I just export the entire root directory of the site. All the configs, paths, etc are all the same. But no matter how exact I get, it still wont reflect an changes I make to the file on PC 2. Is there seriously no simple way to take a site with symlinks from one pc to another? Thanks again.

Comment: Everythign should be fine as long as you are using realative symlinks like `ln -s ../source/lib library` (At least in the *nix worlld.. not sure how it plays out on windows boxes) if youre using absolute paths then yes, there are going to be problems because the path may not be the same between the two boxes. Ive never had this issue with a filesystem export from Eclipse (OS X, BSD, Debian, Solaris) so long as the links are relative.

Comment: Also are you sying that this issue is only with the symlinked files or is it a general issue with all files I have a feeling i may be misunderstanding some of the details of your question.

Comment: No, they are relative paths. I guess I don't really understand what my problem is. Say, for example, I copy from one machine to another. For some reason, when I make a change to the copied file's code. That change will not reflect on my localhost (if copied). If I run the entire setup again, it works. Why is that?

Comment: As far I can tell, it seems to be only with files and directories that are symlinked. http://solarphp.com/manual/blog-demo.app 1.6 is an example of the files and dir that are not updating when being editing on machine 2.

Comment: Are you copying the contents of `tmp/cache` and then not clearing the cache before running the app?

Comment: I am not in front of my dev machine as of right now. I will double check when I get home and see if that is the problem. I can say that I did copy the tmp/cache folder of the root directory. Because I just exported my whole root directory. Could that be the problem? I know I cleared the browser cache on the machine that the files were copied to. I will verify. Thanks.

Comment: Well it depends on what Solar caches... Im not familiar enough with it nor do i know exactl what type of file youre modifying (Model, View, Controller) to be sure... But I would wager views are most definitely cached and if thats is what you're modifying and you are copying the contents of the cache directory that would probably explain it.